# How to make multiple objects work at same time?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, oop

I have been using Python to control some instruments, which I created a Class for. I have multiple instruments of the same kind, so my script has multiple instances of the same class.

Let's say the class is `Arm`, and it has methods `move_left`, `move_right` and `reset`. Right now I have script like this:

```
arm1 = Arm()
arm2 = Arm()
arm1.move_left()
arm2.move_left()
arm1.move_right()
arm2.move_right()
arm1.reset()
arm2.reset()
```

It's completely in serial. I have to wait for `arm1` to finish `move_left`, then start `arm2` to `move_left`. This is very inefficient. I would like `arm1` and `arm2` to move at the same time. They don't have to be *exact* same time, because `arm1` and `arm2` are quite independent and there's not much synchronization requirement. I just don't want to waste time in the serialization in the code.

I've done some searching and learned a little about threading, but what I found is all about putting a *function* in a Thread target, which doesn't really apply to my situation here.

Comment: You told us that `arm1.move_left()` takes some time, let's say ten seconds. What is happening during that time? Are we issuing step step step commands to a stepper motor, and sleep()ing while it advances to next step? You want to immediately `return` rather than `sleep()`, so you can interleave the arm1 & arm2 commands over the ten seconds. Only the toplevel event loop should sleep. Your code should not sleep. It's not clear that Threads will be necessary or will even be the most helpful technique.

Comment: `move_left` is a series of commands. This is a simple example, there are more complicated actions that takes more steps and much longer to finish. I just don't understand, since the two equipment are independent, why can't I let the two objects run their own method at the same time? Why one has to wait for another?

Comment: I'm suggesting that the appropriate way to think about it is, rather than a ten-second move_left(), you really want start_move_left(target=n). So you'd be changing the _state_ of the arm controller, changing it to MOVING, and the controller would eventually notice the arm reached the desired stopping point and would change state back to HALTED. With that in place, you can easily do back-to-back calls where arms 1 & 2 start_move_left(), and you hang out for ten seconds till they've arrived.

Comment: Again, the sleep / wait belongs in the toplevel event loop. If you accomplish the same thing with Threads that's fine, the code will look a bit different, but what the system _does_ will be fundamentally the same. Jeremy Friesner's suggestion makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach the problem would be to implement a *state machine*.  That is, instead of defining the problem through commands like `move_left()` and `move_right()`, instead you can have some variables that represent the final position that you want each arm to end up at, and a second set of variables that represent the current position of the arm.  Then at each time-step, you simply move the arms by a small amount towards their target-destination.

Here's a very simple toy program to demonstrate the idea.  Note that it moves each "arm" by no more than 0.1 units every 100mS time-step (you can of course use any time-step and maximum-movement values you want instead):

```
import time

class Robot:
   def __init__(self):
      self._leftArmCurrentPos  = 0.0
      self._leftArmTargetPos   = 0.0
      self._rightArmCurrentPos = 0.0
      self._rightArmTargetPos  = 0.0

   def setLeftArmTargetPos(self, newPos):
      self._leftArmTargetPos = newPos

   def setRightArmTargetPos(self, newPos):
      self._rightArmTargetPos = newPos

   # Returns the closest value to (deltaVal) in the range [-0.1, +0.1]
   def clamp(self, deltaVal):
      aLittleBit = 0.1  # or however much you want
      if (deltaVal > aLittleBit):
         return aLittleBit
      elif (deltaVal < -aLittleBit):
         return -aLittleBit
      else:
         return deltaVal

   def moveArmsTowardsTargetPositions(self):
      leftArmDelta = self.clamp(self._leftArmTargetPos - self._leftArmCurrentPos)
      if (leftArmDelta != 0.0):
         self._leftArmCurrentPos += leftArmDelta
         print("Moved left arm by %f towards %f, new left arm pos is %f" % (leftArmDelta, self._leftArmTargetPos, self._leftArmCurrentPos))

      rightArmDelta = self.clamp(self._rightArmTargetPos - self._rightArmCurrentPos)
      if (rightArmDelta != 0.0):
         self._rightArmCurrentPos += rightArmDelta
         print("Moved right arm by %f towards %f, new right arm pos is %f" % (rightArmDelta, self._rightArmTargetPos, self._rightArmCurrentPos))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   r = Robot()
   r.setLeftArmTargetPos(10.0)
   r.setRightArmTargetPos(-3.0)

   while True:
      r.moveArmsTowardsTargetPositions()
      time.sleep(0.1)
```

A nice side-effect of this approach is that you if change your mind at any time about where you want the arms to be, you can simply call `setLeftArmTargetPos()` or `setRightArmTargetPos()` to give the arms new/different destination values, and they will immediately start moving from (wherever they currently are at) towards the new target positions -- there's no need to wait for them to arrive at the old destinations first.

Comment: By splitting up the action into small time steps, at each time step you're still moving one arm at a time, isn't it? So the two arms "appear" to move at same time but it doesn't really save me any time.

Comment: That's going to depend on how the underlying move-the-arm call is implemented.  Ideally you'd have an implementation of it that returns as soon as the command has been sent to the motor, rather than waiting/blocking until the arm has indicated that it has finished moving by the specified amount.  In the latter case, you're right, you'd have two arms both moving at half-speed (and I doubt multithreading would help in that case either, since an API that simple/high-level is unlikely to be thread-safe)